# Why are Fullscreen Photos taken by Camera on iphone not displayed in UIImageview when allowsEditing is disabled?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, camera

In my app I take photos from the iPhone camera and put those photos into an ScrollView with images.

The problem is that it only works in my case if I set

```
picker.allowsEditing = YES
```

But in this case the photos will only saved in a square form (thanks to allowsEditing ther is a selection square in the camera function).

If i take out this line of code (what I want since I want the complete photo and not only a selected sqaure of it), then the placeholder image is just replaced by nothing.

Here are the needed methods:

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender{
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
//picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:[self getCurrentPageNumber]];
UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
image.image = chosenImage;
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];}

-(void)addImageToImageScrollView:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height {
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]; 
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imgView setTag:([self getCurrentPageNumber]+1)];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageScrollViewButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
[button setTag:([self getCurrentPageNumber]+1)];    
[view addSubview:imgView];
[view addSubview:button];
[imageScrollView addSubview:view];}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate protocol

When you set `allowsEditing` to yes, then you will start receiving an NSDictionary full of useful info when the delegate method fires:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
```

You are consuming some of this info when you call `UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImages];`

by setting `allowsEditing` to `NO` the delegate method will pass nil in for the `info` argument.

You can confirm this by setting a breakpoint in your method, stepping in and observing that the `info` will be nil, implying that you are setting your *chosenImage to nil.

Comment: Ok, I understand. So I guess with this method I can't take fullscreen photos? Or is there another function instead where I can remove that photolimitation square?

Comment: I probably should have been more specific here, it's the "Editing Information Keys" that change in the dictionary which is returned, not the unedited info itself. You are specifically asking for the edited image when you pass in UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage, when I think what you want is UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage.

Comment: You can quickly see for yourself what is present in the <code>info</code> dictionary that you get by setting a breakpoint and drilling into that variable.

Comment: I found my mistake istead of "UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];" I have to use "UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];"

Comment: Ah you commented that also. Thanks for that.

Comment: Absolutely!  I wanted to offer more understanding of the process than just a simple "switch the constant you are passing" answer, since you went to the trouble to play around and figure out what change you made was triggering the bad behavior. Good luck!